# Can $W^\pm$ bosons act by changing the weak isospin state of particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra, weak-interaction, electroweak

From what I understand, the weak isospin part of the symmetry-unbroken electroweak interaction consists of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ valued gauge field $\hat W_\mu = \sum_i^3W^i_\mu \hat T^i$, where $\{\hat T^i\}_{i=1,2,3}$ are the weak isospin operators which form a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ generators and obey the following commutation relations:
$$[\hat T^i,\hat T^j] = \sum^3_k i\varepsilon^{ijk}\hat T^k$$

An alternate basis is the adjoint action eigenbasis of $\hat T^3$,
\begin{align}
\hat T^+ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\hat T^1+i\hat T^2),\; [\hat T^3, \hat T^+] = +\hat T^+ \\
\hat T^- &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\hat T^1-i\hat T^2),\; [\hat T^3, \hat T^-] = -\hat T^- \\
\hat T^0 &= \hat T^3,\; [\hat T^3, \hat T^0] = 0\hat T^0
\end{align}
The component fields of $\hat W_\mu$ in this basis are:
\begin{align}
W^+_\mu &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(W^1_\mu - iW^2_\mu) \\
W^-_\mu &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(W^1_\mu + iW^2_\mu) \\
W^0 &= W^3
\end{align}
So that $\hat W_\mu = \hat W^+_\mu\hat T^+ + \hat W^-_\mu\hat T^- + \hat W^0_\mu\hat T^0$.

As the non-zero root vectors for $\hat T^3$, the $\hat T^\pm$ operators are ladder operators for the 3rd component of weak isospin, in the sense that their action in a representation is to transform weak isospin eigenstates to weak isospin eigenstates of higher/lower eigenvalue until reaching highest/lowest weights of the rep. e.g. In the adjoint representation, $[\hat T^+,\hat T^-] = \hat T^0$ (increase by 1), $[\hat T^-,\hat T^+] = -\hat T^0$ (decrease by 1), $[\hat T^+,\hat T^+] = 0$ (highest weight), $[\hat T^-,\hat T^-] = 0$ (lowest weight).

The $\hat T^\pm$ operators of course correspond to the two $W^\pm$ gauge bosons, so I am wondering how their ladder operator structure plays a role in the weak interaction.

My idea of how this would work is, given a weak isospin $\frac12$ spinor, $\Psi = (\psi_{\frac12}, \psi_{-\frac12})$ the $W_\mu^\pm$ components of the gauge field would act something like:
$$W_\mu^+\hat T^+\Psi = W_\mu^+(\psi_{-\frac12}, 0)$$
$$W_\mu^-\hat T^-\Psi = W_\mu^-(0,\psi_{\frac12} )$$

However I only seem to read about interactions with $W^\pm$ interactions changing particles from one type to another, and not changing their weak isospin state. So my question is, is this type of 'weak isospin changing' interaction possible? Thanks.

Edit: While researching and rewriting this question I learned that I had a big misconception about weak isospin, where I didn't understand that the weak isospin of an elementary particle is specified by its exact value, unlike regular spin where it determines the range of possible spin states. My main question was essentially if something like a weak isospin 1/2 electron could be transformed into a weak isospin -1/2 electron, which in retrospect makes no sense. Instead, when particles change species through the mediation of a $W^\pm$ boson, their weak isospin changes in the according to that boson's ladder operator (absorb $W^\pm$ to increment weak isospin by $\pm 1$, emit $W^\pm$ to decrement weak isospin by $\pm 1$, e.g. electron capture). So I find that the answer to my title question is a definitive "Yes", but not in the way I originally thought.

Comment: Ts are matrices, Ws are numbers.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand that the Ts are matrices but In the case that the Ws are numbers I don't know how to make sense of the combination $W^\pm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(W_1 \mp iW_2)$, considering the gauge fields are Lie algebra valued. $W^\pm$ would be the coefficient of some new basis element of the Lie algebra but this change of basis formula can't hold for all values of $W_1$ and $W_2$ while keeping that new basis the same.

Comment: No, you got it wrong: the three $W^a$ are *not* Lie-Algebra valued. They are numbers in the adjoint rep of the algebra, so $\vec W\cdot \vec T$ are matrices, Lie-Algebra valued. Once the students/readers appreciate that, people play fast and loose in tagging the *numbers* $W^a$  and the matrices   $W\equiv \vec W\cdot \vec T$ by similar wordings...

Comment: @CosmasZachos The notation I tried to define in the first paragraph was meant to correspond to what you just said, something like $W = \vec w\cdot\vec T = W_1 + W_2 + W_3$ where those terms on the RHS are the projections onto the Ts: $W_1 = w_1 T, W_2 = w_2 T_3, W_3 = w_3 T_3$, with $w_i$ being numbers. I had originally treated the Ws as just number coefficients but then the definitions of $W^\pm$ (and Z and A bosons) seemed strange because if $X = (W_1,W_2,W_3,B)\cdot(T_1,T_2,T_3,Y_W)$ then what basis should be used so that $X = (W^+, W^-, Z^0, A)\cdot(?,?,?,?)$ given those expressions.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Never mind the question I just asked in my previous comment (not that it even makes sense), I've now realized the mistake I've been making with regards to numbers vs matrices. Very sorry for wasting your time on that topic.

Comment: You might edit your question on the basis of this conversation, then...

Comment: I'm a little confused by the downvotes on this question (v2, even though the downvotes seem to have been applied to v1). Asking a question which is a little bit muddled, because the asker has made some important incorrect assumption in the middle, is a normal part of the learning process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypercharge, commuting with the three Pauli matrices, $\vec \tau$, is the 2d identity matrix, so the overall matrix of the gauge fields (all numbers here) coupling to, e.g., the Higgs doublet looks like
$$
\vec W \cdot \vec \tau + \tan \theta_w ~ B~{\mathbb I}= \begin{pmatrix} \tan \theta_w ~ B+W^3 & \sqrt{2} W^+\\
\sqrt{2} W^-& \tan \theta_w ~ B-W^3  \end{pmatrix} \\
= \begin{pmatrix} 2\sin\theta_w ~ A+{\cos 2\theta_w\over \cos \theta_w} Z & \sqrt{2} W^+\\
\sqrt{2} W^-&  -Z/\cos \theta_w   \end{pmatrix}.
$$
From the covariant kinetic term of the Higgs, after you reinstate the spacetime indices *μ*, you may now compute the vacuum-value induced mass terms.

This matrix, indeed, may change the third component of isospin through the charge current interaction. When you write sandwiches of this matrix between two spinors, you may quickly observe if such hamiltonian terms  conserve
charge. If they do not, you have made a mistake! For example, for leptons (take the first family for simplicity), since their hypercharge is exactly the opposite of that of the Higgs doublet, above, you have
$$
\overline{(\nu,e)_L} ~(\vec W \cdot \vec \tau - \tan \theta_w ~ B~{\mathbb I})_\mu \gamma^\mu ~\begin{pmatrix}\nu\\ e \end{pmatrix}_L \\ 
 = \overline{(\nu,e)_L}\begin{pmatrix} Z/\cos \theta_w  & \sqrt{2} W^+\\
\sqrt{2} W^-&- 2\sin\theta_w ~ A-   {\cos 2\theta_w\over \cos \theta_w} Z \end{pmatrix}\cdot \gamma \begin{pmatrix}\nu\\ e \end{pmatrix}_L .
$$
Observe how each term is charge neutral and the couplings comport with the compact setup of the [PDG sec 10.1](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/web/viewer.html?file=../reviews/rpp2023-rev-standard-model.pdf).

<sub>Geeky:  Observe the celebrated vanishing of the vector coupling of the *Z* acting on the  L charged lepton, the electron, for $ \theta_w = \pi/6$, a value quite close to the physical one!)</sub>

---

*Addendum in response to comment/question by @Craig on the action of $g_V$ on the charged L leptons here*:

<sub>By the PDG (10.6a,b), $g_V e_L= (-1/2 +2\sin^2\theta_w)e_L\sim 0$, so the L-sector of the last term of (10.2) reduces to
$$
{g\over 2\cos\theta_w} \overline{e_L}\not{\!\! Z}(-P_L+2\sin^2\theta_w)e_L\\ 
=-{g\over 2\cos\theta_w} \overline{e_L}\not{\!\! Z}(P_L-2\sin^2\theta_w)e_L\\ =-{g\over 2\cos\theta_w} \overline{e_L}\not{\!\! Z}(\cos 2\theta_w)e_L\sim 
-{g\over 4\cos\theta_w} \overline{e_L}\not{\!\! Z}e_L ,
$$
opposite of the neutrino term, as compared to the answer's expression.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand your geeky comment about vanishing coupling. The coefficient on $ \frac{\cos 2\theta_w}{\cos \theta_w}\bar{e}_L Z_\mu \gamma^\mu e_L$ term is $1/\sqrt{3}$ for the quoted angle, and it is zero for $\pi/4$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are: You are comparing the PDG (10.2) with (10.6a) acting on L chiral fermions, only, ignoring R chiral ones for this. What is it you find? Recall the 1/cos θ coefficient is common!

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be harmful to put in an addendum to that point:)

Comment: I did. I left the R charged leptons out, since they never turned up in the question, but you may see from the PDG that $\gamma^5$ acting on them amounts to the identity, so you may also take, in that limit, $g_V=0$, instead of their $g_A=0$!